# Converting block address into csv file

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

Suppose I have a text file of the following form

```
Name1
Address 1.1
Address 1.2
Pincode 1

Name2
Address 2.1
Address 2.2
Pincode 2
```

Is there a way to write a script in sed or awk which creates a csv file of the following form

```
Name1;Address 1.1;Address 1.2;Pincode1
Name2;Address 2.1;Address 2.2;Pincode2
```

Any help will be much appreciated. I have a huge text file with such address and I want to make a database out of it.

Comment: Sometimes there might be Address 1.3 in some of the address which make it have an extra line inthe address block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk idiomatically as designed/intended:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' -v OFS=';' '{$1=$1}1' file
Name1;Address 1.1;Address 1.2;Pincode 1
Name2;Address 2.1;Address 2.2;Pincode 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this one-liner a try:

```
awk -v RS="" 'gsub(/\n/,";")' file
Name1;Address 1.1;Address 1.2;Pincode 1
Name2;Address 2.1;Address 2.2;Pincode 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this -

```
sed '/^$/d' f | awk -v FS=";" ' {ORS=(NR%4==0?RS:FS)}1'
Name1;Address 1.1;Address 1.2;Pincode 1
Name2;Address 2.1;Address 2.2;Pincode 2
```

If there is no blank line we can remove the sed command.